# Trying to understand Timestamps in Java (Discord JDA & Mongodb)

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

Please take a look at the image attached.

[image: Discord Bot]

If you type in "prefix + start" the bot will count down and fill up your "backpack".
If you type in "prefix + collect" it will collect all items from the "backpack" and reset the item count.

I know how to set up a database and how to connect a discord bot to it. (mongodb, discord jda)

Still, I don't understand how this was solved. They save an initial timestamp in the database and subtract the elapsed time? Maybe someone can help me ^^

Answer (score 0):

This will mostly depend on what database you're using. But because it's MongoDB, I'll go with that.

To connect to the MongoDB database, there are a few libraries that you can use. I suggest using the [MongoDB Default Library for Java](https://www.mongodb.com/java). Once that's done, you can use some of the [MongoDB BSON Types](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/) (Specifically type 17). You can get the current time, and the time in the database and compare them to each other. From this time, you can get the relative time and how much time there is still left until a refill.